# Titan: Gremlin or Java for efficient time based graph queries

Tags: gremlin, titan

I have the following simple graph of time based IP->FQDN mappings.

[image]

I created this graph as follows

```
TitanManagement mgmt = graph.getManagementSystem();

VertexLabel ip = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("ip").make();
VertexLabel fqdn = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("fqdn").make();
EdgeLabel bind = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("bind").make();
final PropertyKey name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(String.class).make();
TitanGraphIndex namei = mgmt.buildIndex("name", Vertex.class).addKey(name).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(namei, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
final PropertyKey timestamp = mgmt.makePropertyKey("timestamp").dataType(Integer.class).make();
mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(bind, "bindByTime", Direction.BOTH, Order.DESC, timestamp);

mgmt.commit();

TitanTransaction tx = graph.newTransaction();

Vertex ip1 = tx.addVertexWithLabel("ip");
ip1.setProperty("name", "ip1");
Vertex ip2 = tx.addVertexWithLabel("ip");
ip2.setProperty("name", "ip2");
Vertex fqdn1 = tx.addVertexWithLabel("fqdn");
fqdn1.setProperty("name", "fqdn1");
Vertex fqdn2 = tx.addVertexWithLabel("fqdn");
fqdn2.setProperty("name", "fqdn2");
ip1.addEdge("bind", fqdn1).setProperty("timestamp", 1);
ip2.addEdge("bind", fqdn2).setProperty("timestamp", 2);
ip1.addEdge("bind", fqdn2).setProperty("timestamp", 3);

tx.commit();
```

I am now in the process of writing a query which finds the fqdn that an ip was bound to at a given time. Some examples follow

- fqdnFor(ip="ip1", timestamp=1) == fqdn1
- fqdnFor(ip="ip1", timestamp=2) == fqdn1
- fqdnFor(ip="ip1", timestamp=3) == fqdn2
- fqdnFor(ip="ip1", timestamp=4) == fqdn2

Here is the gremlin query I have written to compute this, I believe this is correct given for example (ip='ip1', t=4).

```
g.V.has('name', ip)
    .outE.has('timestamp', LESS_THAN_EQUAL, t)
    .order()
    .last()
    .inV()
```

My questions are now as follows.

1. How would I modify this gremlin query to return not just the vertex
   but also the edge that lead to it.
2. Is this query optimal given the indexes I have created? If I understand the bindByTime index correctly this query should be as efficient (take the same computation time) even if the graph depicted above contained for example a million bind edges (t1, t2, ... t1000000) outgoing from each ip (ip1, ip2).
3. How would I execute this query from java instead of from the gremlin console? I was hoping to find something akin to JDBC PreparedStatement.

Something like the following sudo code.

```
PreparedGremlinQuery query = new PreparedGremlinQuery("V.has('name', :ip).outE.has('timestamp', LESS_THAN_EQUAL, :t).order().last().inV()");
query.put(1, "ip1");
query.put(2, 3);   
Result r = query.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Q1 seems to be use a combination of as and select.

```
g.V.has('name', 'ip1').outE.has('timestamp', LESS_THAN_EQUAL, 3).order().last().as('e').inV().as('v').select(['e', 'v'])
```

The answer to Q2 seems to be yes if I use orderBy() see [quote from the Titan 0.5 docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html#_ordering) below.

> Mixed indexes support ordering natively and efficiently. However, the
>   property key used in the orderBy method must have been previously
>   added to the mixed indexed for native result ordering support. This is
>   important in cases where the orderBy key is different from the query
>   keys. If the property key is not part of the index, then sorting
>   requires loading all results into memory.

However I cannot seem to use orderBy()

```
g.V.has('name', 'ip1').outE.has('timestamp', LESS_THAN_EQUAL, 3).orderBy('timestamp', Order.DESC).last().as('e').inV().as('v').select(['e', 'v'])
```

I get the following exception

> No signature of method:
>   com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline.orderBy() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String,
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.Order) values: [timestamp, DESC] Possible
>   solutions: order(), order(com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens$T),
>   order(com.tinkerpop.pipes.PipeFunction),
>   order(com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.TransformPipe$Order),
>   order(groovy.lang.Closure), every()

The answer to Q3 seems to be no not really. Nothing on the following page seems to resemble PreparedStatement which is very readable and protects against query injection.

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java